# Resetting In-App Purchases (testflight, sandbox)

Tags: in-app-purchase, reset, testflight

My purchases won't reset.

I have done everything that can be found online. I've made multiple (sandbox and testflight) accounts, uninstalled apps, logged in and out tenths of times. Whatever I do, whenever I return into an app in which I have made purchases previously, those items are still purchased. It seems like the device is remembered for the purchases, instead of the user.

Before, if I re-installed an application with Testflight, everything would be reset. This way I could test if in-app purchases kept working. Now, I have to ask my developer to create a weird workaround to reset purchases.

Does anybody have any clue what can be done about this, or has experienced the same problem? I'm working with an iPad Air 2, the problem has started since updating to iOS 10.0...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Often questions can be answered faster and more accurately by providing a code sample. Please read this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)